# exclude one subdomain from serving via https on apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

**little intro:**

I have SSL cert for specific domains (`example.com, info.example.com, intranet.example.com`, ...)

All domains except the `info.example.com` are running on Apache. `info.example.com` is running on windows server.

**My problem**
All sites are fully working, but I have problem with `info.example.com` which I dont want to server as "HTTPS" (yet). But I do have a permanent redirect in my VirtualHosts... and that makes the problem -> when I visit `info.example.com`, it redirect me to `https://info.example.com` which I don't want to. If I delete permanent redirect it will works, but I don't want to serve anything via http on my `example.com`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin user@user.com
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
     ServerName example.com
     Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I wouldn't even ask here, because it must be something really stupid, but I'm struggling with this too long.

Excuse my english.

Comment: `All domains except the info.example.com are running on Apache. info.example.com is running on windows server.` So info.example.com  doesn't run on Apache ? you should correct this, else your question doesn't have any meaning. And the (Apache) configuration you posted is about `example.com` and not `info.example.com` as you are asking. You should open your 2 eyes instead of using only one in your pyramid fingers.

Comment: I don't have access to windows server for `info.example.com` and since it doesn't run on apache I don't even know it it's possible to manage virtualhost for this.  
I guess, I'm asking really wrong - consider me as "newbie"-, but i just want to exclude `info.example.com` from serving via https. and I've noticed that when I delete permanent redirect in my `example.com` it's working, so I though there could be something like permanent redirect only to `www.example.com` domain and not redirect whole second level domain - `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

If what you are saying is true, just replace

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

by

```
RewriteEngine on 
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^info\.example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and don't forget to enable mod_rewrite (`a2enmod rewrite`)